# Android animations not smooth

Tags: android, animation, timertask

I am developing a game, where in I have used a timer task, which needs to continuously run to update the GUI. Here if I try to execute 2 animations simultaneously, they do not work smoothly, and animations look very choppy.

For example, even if I execute a frame animation, and while its running, I try to scroll a list, it wont scroll smoothly as desired. I tried running a few animations in runOnUiThread, but had no luck.

I have also noticed one more thing. Using image.setVisibility(View.GONE) or image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), disrupts the animation flow.

Please suggest a solution or an alternative to this issue. Does executing multiple animations simultaneously cause problems in android?

Answer (score 4):

What is your target API? Can you turn [hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) on?

```
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Comment: Hey OceanLife, I have been testing the animations on real device and I am targetting devices with Android 2.3. I suppose hardware acceleration is supported from Android 3.0, so that may not help my other devices.

Comment: In that case I'd go back to making your View-Controller code as efficient as possible wrt to recycling views. Perhaps inefficiencies elsewhere are manifesting as a slow animation when that isn't the route cause. You can also profile your code using the DDMS tooling and identify which bits of code are running inefficiently. Another give away is if you seen GC (Garbage Collection) constantly logging whilst your app is running. Every now and again is fine but GCs in quick succession would suggest the concurrent garbage collector (it's Concurrent in more recent releases of Android) is struggling.

Comment: I am not calling garbage collection in my code explicitly, and yes I am using AsyncTasks for heavy background calculations. I think the Drawable animations require more RAM, and hence are slow. I cant find any other alternative to it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas. If the app is animation intensive and this is a hardware limitation then perhaps some market filtering maybe in order until you can get it sorted. Set-up a small-screened 3.2 honeycomb emulator and turn on GPU emulation and see how that works. Admittedly it will still be slower but with the GPU hardware and smaller screen size the emulator should give a representative performance.

Answer (score 1):

if you have only been testing on the emulator, maybe you can try on a real device first. I believe it is known that the emulator is not the best at rendering animations like a real device would.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot expect fluid animations for android versions before 4.0 (Ice cream Sandwich).
Try to run them on later android versions and you will find huge differences.

Answer (score 0):

The reply is a bit late but I had the same problem recently and figured out a way to solve it, so for those interested...

Obviously, if your view is moving over others, those are forced to be redrawn. One way to prevent too much redrawing is to flatten your view hierarchy.

However, when you have several animations at a time, this may not be enough. In that case, if your programming for devices where hardware acceleration is enabled, disabling it on views that are redrawn, such as background views, can help (call `View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`, for instance). I don't really know why, but it smooths the animations quite well. Perhaps because the GPU doesn't have too handle all redrawings.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience memory use can effect the performance of the animations. 
So if you can decrease the memory footprint of the app, it might have a positive impact. One easy way to do that is to reduce the file size of any images you are using.